# Access a folder inside my VirtualBox from outside

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu in my VirtualBox on Windows 7.

How can I access a folder inside the virtual Ubuntu?

All I found out is the other direction: shared folders, but they are all Windows folders without the user-permissions I need inside the virtual machine.

---

I found out thanks to *Serge*:

Samba, FTP, or SSH would be the solution, but I couldn't access the IP of my virtual machine at first.

I had to enable the network connection. I tried the options "NAS" and "Internal Network" but that doesn't work.

I had to use the Network Bridge.

Comment: What do you mean `the other direction`. Shared folders are for passing data from host->client and vice versa

Comment: i need a folder where i can use symbolic linux links to other folders, but i want to write also into it from windows.

Comment: `What do you mean the other direction. Shared folders are for passing data from host->client and vice versa` This only works if files are written to the shared folder inside the VM. The OP was asking about accessing folders on the VIRTUAL-DRIVE inside the VM from the host. - It's not the same as using a shared-folder, but one way is to spin down the VM and mount its disk-file (assuming the VM software supports that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numerous options:

- ftp server inside Ubuntu VM
- samba server inside VM
- ssh (use pscp from putty package)
- ...

Comment: how do i find out the ip then? i cannot ping the ip, i find in ifconfig: (10.0.2.15) and ssh doesen't work either

Comment: then you need to inspect the config of your VM if you enabled the networking at all, e.t.c.

Comment: i have, but which option? NAT? Internal Network?

Comment: check if the firewall (iptables) is enabled in VM and what rules are active.

Comment: `iptalbes -L` sais all open

Comment: I found it: I have to use "Network bridge" thx for your help